# Asynchronous function call in Drupal 7

Tags: php, asynchronous, drupal, drupal-7

I’m working on a Drupal 7 website with lots of forms. I was asked to send those form data to an external API. For that, I have created a set of functions and its basic code structure is as follows

```
function form_data_submit (){
    // get form data and do pre-process
    call_to_function_a ($data);
    call_to_curl_function($data);
    //do other processing 
} 

function call_to_curl_function($data){
    //prepared data
    //send to API using cURL
}
```

But this “call_to_curl_function()” takes a significant time to return. Because of that end-users have to wait. Sometimes this caused timeout error. I don’t want “call_to_curl_function()” return values to proceed further in “form_data_submit()”.

Is there is a way I can just call the “call_to_curl_function()” function and the without waiting for its return, move to the “do other processing” part?

As I understand I need to run either cURL call or "call_to_curl_function()" asynchronous. I have searched about asynchronous functions in Drupal and cURL. Also tried some of them, but was unable to find a solution for this.
I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: I think that Drupal queues should help you with it. They allow to process some actions later (call_to_curl_function in your case):https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.queue.inc/group/queue/7.x

Comment: @SerhiiPuchkovskyi Thanks for the info, I'll check this and get back